# php display date based on text value of day from database

Tags: php, html

I have a request that returns a day value from a db eg Friday.

With in my php code I need to then display this as a day in the format of

```
l jS \of F
```

so that it reads Friday 31st of March

If it was run next Monday, the value would again be Friday but the date I display is Friday 7th of April.

From a text value how to I return a date associated with that value.

What I have done so far is as follows:

$result is the day i.e. Friday

```
echo date("l jS \of F", strtotime( $result ));
```

This kind of works but not sure if its the best way.

Comment: Please post your code what you did so far and what exactly is not working

Comment: Please give some example. so that we can help you out.

Comment: @Ann-Sophie Angermüller updated with code, thanks.

Comment: yeah its correct . it will give the result by what format your given for your given date

Comment: @TJ15 your code seems OK (it'll give you same the Friday on a Friday and next Friday on any other day). But make sure you test your code thoroughly.